# Identifying and sending an e-mail in outlook using Geb-Groovy framework

Tags: automated-testing

i have a test case where user clicks on a button to send an e-mail and user's default e-mail client opens up. In my case I am using outlook as my default e-mail client. What would be the best way to automate this flow. I am using [the GEB framework](http://www.gebish.org/) and I have never automated any external component before. It would be great if someone could atleast point me to the right direction to start.

Thanks!

Comment: With GEB you mean http://www.gebish.org/ ? Also what do you want to test, that the mail application opens?

Comment: Yes, for both. I want to make sure that the application opens up.

Comment: Does it have to be Outlook's desktop app? You could setup your machine to use any handler for mailto links. Outlook has a web equivalent (or even use gmail) that might be easier to automate.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably two parts to this:

- **Testing every condition that triggers launching an email client.**  I would use a web-based email client for this.
- **Testing the logic that launches email clients.**  Since there are lots of possible clients, and you can't drive these with a web automation framework, I recommend testing this by hand.  If this logic is not expected to change often, it may not make sense to spend money writing/maintaining automated tests for it.

Answer (score 0):

With web-automation frameworks you cannot test beyond the browser.

Tools like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [Auto-IT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) can be triggered (with `Process.Start()` or `Exec()`) from the test to do an action that needs input from the operating system outside of the browser.

In your case I wonder if just checking the button has the correct "mailto:" link would not be enough. The browser [mailto: system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto) always fires up the default browser. You may expect that the operation system supplier has tested that this works for you.

Comment: Thanks. It is not mandated that I test this in outlook. I can also change my default e-mail client to a web based e-mail. In that case how do I proceed?

Comment: Find the new window that opened and continue testing from there? :)